# no me carga la imagen, aparece si! pero un cuadradito chico por default

Tags: html, python, dash

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc 
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd 
from dash.dependencies import Input,Output
df = pd.read_csv('Covid19VacunasAgrupadas.csv')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    
    html.Div([
        html.H1('Vacunados por covid',style = {'text-aling':'center', 'font-style': 'GrindAndDeath_Demo','color':'red', 'margin-top': '40px'}, className = 'dcc_compon'),
        html.Img(src='assets/vacunas.png')
])
])


if __name__ == ('__main__'):
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Buenas, por favor corrige la publicación y explica mejor las cosas.

Comment: Podrias poner la estructura de tus directorios?

Comment: ya esta cris  gracias !!, termine cambiando el png, los archivos css estaban bien la imagen nose por que quedo asi pero en fin., ahora si funciona.